# Adding an Azure-hosted Bot to Microsoft Teams Dev Portal

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an bot hosted in azure running on the new Azure Bot Service. I need to fully connect this bot to teams. According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0):

> Adding a bot by GUID, for anything other than testing purposes, is not recommended. Doing so severely limits the functionality of a bot. Bots in production should be added to Teams as part of an app. Read [Create a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-create) and [Test and debug your Microsoft Teams bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-test) in the Microsoft Teams documents for more information.

The information given points to creating a new bot, solely for Microsoft teams. My bot is not necessarily only for teams. Furthermore, this does not go over Azure hosted bots being connected fully as an application, and looking around in teams' app studio hasn't given me any more insight.

What can I do to connect my bot to teams fully? (I say fully because using the GUID does not allow OAuth functionality, which is pivotal to my bot's usage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use App Studio for this

1. Open MS Teams and click on App Studio
   [image: App Studio]
2. Fill in all the details for your app, company name, URLs are required if you don't have valid details you can enter dummy data for now
   [image]

[image: required fields]

3. Now you need to click on Bots from the left side menu and setup
   [image]
4. Since you have already registered your bot using Azure Bot Service, click on the existing bot and enter your bot App Id. Select the scopes which are applicable for you (Personal, group, team)

[image]

5. Select domains and permissions menu and add your valid domains needed for OAuth functionalities. like "token.botframework.com" or "*.ngrok.io"

[image]

6. Click on test and distribute and click install to add the bot to your teams
   [image]